# Dynamic input field in redux-form. How to rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

So I am pretty new to both React and JavaScript, and I'm working on a project where I need a wizard-form. I then started using redux-form, to make the job easier. But I am struggling with creating dynamic input fields based on a select list.

Intended function is that when choosing 3 in the dropdown list, I will get 3 input fields. I am now able to do this, but only by using a button to update. I don't know how to do this without using a button.

I am using a formValueSelector, because I need to do this in another part of the wizard form also.

I think I would be able to do this, if my Page component was a class with states, but I don't know if I can do this together with redux-form.
Any tips?

```
let renderParts = ({fields, n}) => {
    function update(n) {
        n = Number(n);
        let arr = Array(n).fill(0);
        fields.removeAll();
        arr.map(index =>
        fields.push({})
        )
    }

    return (
    <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => update(n) }>Update</button>
        <ul className="list-inline">
            {fields.map((parts, index) =>
                <li key={index}>
                    <Field name={`${parts}.partLength`} type="number" component={renderField}/>
                </li>
            )}
        </ul>
    </div>
    )
};

let Page = (props) => {
    const { handleSubmit, numFields } = props;
  return (
    <form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field name="numFields" component="select" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
          </Field>
        <FieldArray name="parts" component={renderParts} n={numFields}/>
    </form>
  );
};

Page = reduxForm({
    form: 'wizard',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true
})(Page);

const selector = formValueSelector('wizard')
Page = connect(
    state => {
        const numFields = selector(state, 'numFields');
        return {
            numFields
        }

    }
)(Page)

export default Page;
```

Comment: did you find any solution? I need to do this too.

Comment: I remember I solved this after understanding more about redux-form and redux. Read in the documentation about the action Change, which is in redux-form. So I made an onChange function to the dropdown list, which then dispatched the action Change.